# Google Places Autocomplete country restriction

Tags: google-places-api, restriction, country

Is there a way to make Google Places Autocomplete restricted to one country like France?

I have this: `components=country:fr`

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places&language=fr&components=country:fr&key=API_KEY
```

But this didn't restrict the autocomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me.

```
var input = document.getElementById('city_field');
    var options = {
      types: ['(cities)'],
      componentRestrictions: {country: countryCode},
        language: "en"
    };

    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Double check the parameter name components=country:fr syntax